# How to pass multiple code blocks to template in Nim?

Tags: templates, nim-lang

I would like to pass multiple blocks of code into a template but the syntax for one block does not really hint at how to do that. Is it even supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supported. Example:

```
template foo(block1, block2: untyped): untyped =
  block1
  # do something...
  block2

# now the use
foo:
  echo "hello from block 1"
do: # do keyword does the trick
  echo "hello from block 2"
```